# How do I fix a StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, unhandled

I am getting a `StackOverflowException` in my C# program.

**Cmodel.cs**

```
public class CModel
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    public Vector3 Rotation { get; set; }

    public Vector3 Scale { get; set; }

    public Model Model { get; private set; }

    public BoundingSphere BoundingSphere
    {
        get
        {
            // no need for rotation, as this is a sphere
            Matrix worldTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position); // THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS

            BoundingSphere transformed = BoundingSphere;
            transformed = transformed.Transform(worldTransform);

            return transformed;
        }
    }
    private Matrix[] modelTransforms;
    private GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    private BoundingSphere boundingsphere;
    public CModel(Model Model, Vector3 Position, Vector3 Rotation,
    Vector3 Scale, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
    this.Model = Model;

    modelTransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count];
    Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);

    buildBoundingSphere();
    }


    public void Draw(Matrix View, Matrix Projection)
    {
        // Calculate the base transformation by combining
        // translation, rotation, and scaling
        Matrix baseWorld = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale)
        * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(
        Rotation.Y, Rotation.X, Rotation.Z)
        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
        {
            Matrix localWorld = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]
            * baseWorld;
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                BasicEffect effect = (BasicEffect)meshPart.Effect;
                effect.World = localWorld;
                effect.View = View;
                effect.Projection = Projection;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
        private void buildBoundingSphere()
        {
            BoundingSphere sphere = new BoundingSphere(Vector3.Zero, 0);

            // Merge all the model's built in bounding spheres
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
            {
                BoundingSphere transformed = mesh.BoundingSphere.Transform(
                    modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]);

                sphere = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(sphere, transformed);
            }

            this.boundingsphere = sphere;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing any programmer should do is check the stack. From the OP's question is seems like this has not be done (stack trace was not posted). My answer providers tools for finding the source of problems of this sort. If the OP is unwilling to try and help himself (as the vote down indicates) we should try and help him either.

Comment: @DannyVarod - thank you for the reminder.  I was trying to fix a stack overflow exception where there was no intentional recursion.  Looking at the stack trace showed that the method in question was called repeatedly, and it turned out to be a reference to something that calls the method that was failing.  So... unintentional recursion.

Comment: @Kevin vote ups and "accept answer" are the way to say thanks here :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have a recursive call in your getter which will call itself and cause the `StackOverflowException` :

```
public BoundingSphere BoundingSphere
{
    get
    {
       ...
       BoundingSphere transformed = BoundingSphere;
       ...
    }
}
```

It's not completely clear what you *meant to* write - but if you want to preserve any state you will need a backing field for storing the bounding sphere instead.

Comment: when I do that it gives me an actual error saying "'CModel.BoundingSphere.get': not all code paths return a value"

Comment: @Nate: When you do what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Your get method calls itself: `BoundingSphere` calls `BoundingSphere`.

```
private BoundingSphere _boundingsphere = null;
public BoundingSphere BoundingSphere
{
    get
    {
        // no need for rotation, as this is a sphere
        **Matrix worldTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(Scale)
            * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);**

        BoundingSphere transformed = _boundingsphere;
        transformed = transformed.Transform(worldTransform);

        return transformed;
    }
    set
    {
        _boundingsphere = value;
    }
}
```

When you use following form:

```
public BoundingSphere BoundingSphere { get; set }
```

you don't need to specify variable to store actual value, but when you implement get or set explicitly you should declare additional variable and use it in get, set implementations.

Answer (score -1):

1. Look at the call stack or the exception's stack trace.
2. Identify the loop.
3. Figure out how to break the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're needing to change

```
get 
{ 
    ...
    BoundingSphere transformed = BoundingSphere; // public property
    ...
}
```

to this

```
get 
{ 
    ...
    BoundingSphere transformed = boundingsphere; // private variable
    ...
}
```